# react-native firebase image upload error 404

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an image upload function on react-native using firebase.

This is the error I keep getting:

```
FirebaseStorageError 
{
    "code_": "storage/unknown",
    "message_": "Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response.", 
    "name_": "FirebaseError",
    "serverResponse_": "{\"error\": {\"code\": 404, \"message\": \"Not Found.  Could not access bucket [DEFAULT]\"}}",
}
```

What does this error mean? How can I resolve it?

edit:

this is my code:

```
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : 
        uri
        let uploadBlob = null
        let userImagePath = '0bWgZGQUSnf1wECGo2xi4O1sfWH2' + '/profile'; 
        let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images');

        fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
            .then((data) => {
                return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
            })
            .then((blob) => {
                uploadBlob = blob
                return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
            })
            .then(() => {
                uploadBlob.close()
                return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
            })
            .then((url) => {
                resolve(url)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            })
    })
```

I tried to upload a simple string to the firebase storage but still got the same error.

Comment: Show us your code or we can't help you. Though it sounds like you copied some tutorial code and didn't change something that you were meant to change, going by this bit: `Could not access bucket [DEFAULT]`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a bucket manually in firebase first then you give the same bucket name in the storage bucket name

Answer (score 0):

I have with a similar error with web js so I´ve found the url requisition post was wrong:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[Object object]/o?name=filename
```

right

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/your_budget_nameHere/o?name=filename
```

So to solve I ve just update

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-storage.js?v=1"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-storage.js?v=1"></script>
```